# How to open Facebook profile in Android app with numerical user-id

Tags: android, facebook, url-scheme

I want to open a person's Facebook profile in the native Android app with a given numerical user ID. Note that I am *not* referring to the vanity URL like `www.facebook.com/person.name.7`.

I've tried seemingly every URL scheme including the following with no luck:
`fb://page/426253597411507`
`fb://profile/426253597411507`
`fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/426253597411507`
`https://www.facebook.com/n/?426253597411507`

Does anyone know a URL scheme that currently works? Or a way to get the vanity URL from the profile ID?

Comment: Brother, Have you solve this issue. I need this solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have not. The project requirements have changed so at this time I am not looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try launching an explicit intent [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28200436/3570019)

```
Intent intent = null;
try {
    // get the Facebook app if possible
    this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/{id}"));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // no Facebook app, revert to browser
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://facebook.com/PROFILENAME"));
}
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but no luck. `fb://page/{id}` opens the app with an empty profile, and `fb://profile/{id}` opens the app with a "Content not available" error message

Answer (score 0):

In my case i am loading users profile picture using below code hope may be it will help to you.

```
Picasso.with(Main.this).load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookuserid
                                + "/picture?type=small").resize(80, 80)
                        .into(fbpicImageView);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to open the user's profile in the app itself.